# ¿Porque me dice que la variable no esta definida al enviar los datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios, input

Tengo un botón modal que al pulsarlo me abre un archivo con el contenido del modal en el quiero tener un formulario con un buscador que al buscar me imprima la palabra por medio de php, pero al pulsar el botón no me sale nada sino el error que la variable no esta definida

```html
<?php
$campoNombreBuscar = $_POST['submit'];
echo $campoNombreBuscar;
?>

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtNombreAbBuscar" placeholder="Introduce el nombre del jugador" aria-label="buscador" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="busqueda">Buscar jugador</button>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El problema es que **$_POST['submit']** no existe hasta que haces clic en el botón, entonces debes hacer algo como ```if (isset($_POST['submit'])) : $campoNombreBuscar = $_POST['submit']; // etc... endif;```, otra cosa tu botón no tiene ningún **value='valor'** así que la variable ```$campoNombreBuscar``` va ser vacío siempre. Puedes añadir esta línea dentro del **if** ```var_dump($_POST);``` y así veras los valores que obtienes desde el formulario.

Comment: Nada me sigue saliendo el mismo error de variable nula

Comment: Lee bien todo el comentario que te deje arriba **no tiene ningún valor tu button, va ser vacío siempre** añadele el atributo **value**, ```<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="busqueda" value="buscar">Buscar jugador</button>```, aun así no te va buscar el jugar, creo que estas un poco confuso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error de variable no está definido `$campoNombreBuscar = $_POST['submit'];`, es porque intentas obtener el valor por **$_POST** cuando este no existe, te aconsejo que siempre verifiques que está definida, ejemplo:

```
if (isset($_POST))  { // Trabajas con tu formulario }
```

El segundo error se debe a que tu botón no tiene el atributo `value`, por eso motivo siempre esta vacío.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="busqueda" value="buscar">Buscar jugador</button>
```

**Posible ejemplo**

```
<?php
// Reseteo  ¡importante!
$error = $campoNombreBuscar = '';

// El formulario esta definido
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) :
    // Obtenemos datos
    $campoNombreBuscar = $_POST['txtNombreAbBuscar'] ?? '';
    
    // El input esta vacio
    if (empty($campoNombreBuscar)) $error = 'Introduce el nombre del jugador';

    // Datos son verdaderos
    if ($campoNombreBuscar) :
        // Sigues con tu codigo...
        //
        // Imprimes
        //echo $campoNombreBuscar;
    endif;    
endif;
?>
```

*formulario*

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
                </svg>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtNombreAbBuscar" placeholder="Introduce el nombre del jugador" aria-label="buscador" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value='hello' class="btn btn-primary" id="busqueda">Buscar jugador</button>
        <?php 
            // Esta ya es opcional
            //
            // Errores
            if (isset($error)) echo $error; 
            // Imprimes jugador que buscaste
            if (isset($campoNombreBuscar)) echo $campoNombreBuscar; 
        ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: nada Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: @informaticoDudas ¿has puesto en el atributo ```action=""``` algún URL? Si es así comprueba que este escrito correctamente. Personalmente probe el ejemplo en localhost y me funciono, pruébalo aparte y así lo verificas. Si el formulario se envia en la misma página podrias usar ```action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"```. Otra cosa si no vas a enviar ningún archivo (file) puedes quitar el atributo **enctype**